# Connecting Mule to Salesforce's SOAP based Web Service

Tags: web-services, salesforce, mule, soapui

I am trying to connect MuleSfot to Salesforce SOAP based web service using Web Service Consumer. Trying in SOAPUI first but getting INVALID_SESSION_ID, I need to login in Salesforce to get the ID but not clear. 
Help please!!

**EDIT 1**

Request I am sending

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebService">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
         <allowFieldTruncation>false</allowFieldTruncation>
      </AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
      <DebuggingHeader>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <categories>
            <category>All</category>
            <level>None</level>
         </categories>
         <debugLevel>None</debugLevel>
      </DebuggingHeader>
      <CallOptions>
         <client>?</client>
      </CallOptions>
      <SessionHeader>
         <sessionId>?</sessionId>
      </SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

? for client is fine.
It's session ID which I cant get

**RAW REQUEST**

```
POST https://cs61.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/WebService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 972
Host: cs61.salesforce.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

**RAW RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 04:18:15 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: reflected-xss block;report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=xss
Content-Security-Policy: referrer origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=CdHsqmLzR3OFRklUfp1p3g;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 25-Mar-2017 04:18:15 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/WebService">
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID</faultcode>
<faultstring>INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session</faultstring>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please post more details what you have tried and the issue. Also add the raw request and response.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Needed to login to Salesforce first, used the [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call and get session ID.
Thanks